# Why does OutOfMemoryError occur for -Xmx12m but not -Xmx13m?

Tags: java, out-of-memory, heap-memory

How come if I execute the class below via: `java -Xmx12m OOM`, it fails with the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError Java heap space` message. But if it works with `java -Xmx13m OOM`.

```
class OOM {
  static final int SIZE=2*1024*1024;
  public static void main(String[] a) {
    int[] i = new int[SIZE];
   }
}
```

I thought `int` is 4 bytes so 2*1024*1024*4=8,388,608bytes. It's still lower than 12, right? So how come `-Xmx12m` fails but `-Xmx13m` works?

Comment: There is more memory in use by the JVM besides your array.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I see. But is my analysis of the in array, correct? If so, I wonder what other things are consuming memory.

Comment: A java array also has a fixed `int` length (and `SIZE` so your math is off by 4 to 8 bytes). Other things consuming memory are the constant pools and the JVM itself.

Answer (score 4):

An `-Xmx` option sets the total (maximum) heap size.  However, a Java heap typically consists of 2 (or more) spaces<sup>1</sup>, and a Java object has to fit into a single space.

When you are setting the heap to 12mb, neither of the spaces is large enough<sup>2</sup> to hold a single object of ~8mb.  When you increase the total heap size to 13mb, one of the spaces is big enough.

---

<sup>1 - The "new" or "eden" space is where new objects are normally allocated.  The "old" or "tenured" space is where objects end up after they have survived a certain number of GC cycles.  However, really large objects (like yours) may be allocated directly into the "old" space.  (Note: this is a simplification ...)</sup>

<sup>2 - It is possible to tweak the relative size the new space, but that has other consequences.  For instance, if you reduce the size of the new space too much, you are likely to increase the percentage of "full" GCs ... which affects both throughput and GC pauses.</sup>

Comment: It doesn't appear as though the questioner is setting the heap in gigs, rather in megabytes.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: Just to be clear, when you use "gb", do you actually mean "mb"? In my example, I thought 12m means 12megabytes, no?

Comment: Yes, -Xmx12m sets the size of the heap to 12 megabytes, not gigabytes.

Comment: 1) My mistake, fixed.  2) No it doesn't materially affect the answer.  3) Why are you messing around with heaps so small?  I hope you realize that if you "squeeze" the heap size, you are liable to make the GC less efficient.

Comment: @StephenC I tried to profile his code with Java 8 and I could not see the allocation going into the heap memory. In fact I can see the usage in the non heap memory or the metaspace. Pool Name Type Used(bytes) Max(bytes) Usage(%) Peak Used(bytes) Peak Max(bytes)
Metaspace NON_HEAP 9,612,816   9,612,816 
PS Old Gen HEAP 2,998,376 8,388,608 35.743 2,998,376 8,388,608  
PS Eden Space HEAP 2,014,088 3,145,728 64.026 3,145,728 3,145,728  
Code Cache NON_HEAP 5,227,456 251,658,240 2.077 5,238,144 251,658,240  
Compressed Class Space NON_HEAP 1,114,568 1,073,741,824 0.104 1,114,568 1,073,741,824

Comment: @DROY - The actual details of heap sizes, space sizes, and where huge objects get allocated will depend on all sorts of things ... including what specific version of the JVM you are using.  My basic explanation is the same.  The total size of the heap is not the same as the size of the largest heap you can allocate because the Java heap is not single contiguous region.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Stephan C.

I would like to provide some more info from this [blog](https://anturis.com/blog/java-virtual-machine-the-essential-guide/) by Alexey Zhebel

Below diagram explains java memory architecture in detail.

**Heap memory (-Xmx) = Youn gen (Eden space) + Survivor Space + Olde gen(Tenured space)**

It seems that your total heap memory is crossing 12m but not exceeding 13m.

[image]